# Pass string with quotes as variables to dbt/Jinja

Tags: jinja2, quotes, dbt

I try to run some `dbt` code and hand over a variable that includes quotes:

```sql
SELECT
    field_1,
    field_2    
FROM
    {{ source('schema', 'table') }}
WHERE
    region IN ({{ var("regions") }}) -- ( 'NY', 'WA' )
```

This is the command with which I call it:

```bash
dbt compile -s model --vars '{"regions": "'NY', 'WA'"}'
```

but it always get compiled to this and the quotes get stripped:

```sql
region IN ( NY, WA )
```

I tried to escape it using `"/'NY/', /'WA/'"` or using brackets `"{'NY', 'WA'}"`. But couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Typically backslashes (```\```) are used for escaping characters, not forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: Thanks, but didnt help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend changing your input slightly to pass in the array and building the in list.

```
{%- macro build_in_list(fields, prefix='', postfix='') -%}
  (
  {%- for element in fields -%}
    {%- if element is number -%}
      {{ element }}
    {%- else -%}
      {%- set element = prefix ~ element ~ postfix -%}
      '{{ element }}'
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- if not loop.last -%} , {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
  )
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Then call it in your model with

```
SELECT
    field_1,
    field_2    
FROM
    {{ source('schema', 'table') }}
WHERE
    region IN {{ build_in_list(fields=var('regions', [])) }} -- ( 'NY', 'WA' )
```

Finally, run it using

```
dbt compile -s model --vars '{"regions": ["NY", "WA"]}'
```

If you need just a simple quoted input outside of an in list, you can use a much simper version:

```
{%- macro quoted_var(field) -%}
  '{{ var(field) }}'
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this would work. But is there really no way to escape the quotes?

Comment: I don't think so. but why would you even want to? You're mixing SQL syntax with JSON. Keep your JSON as pure JSON and use Jinja to produce SQL which is what DBT is intended to do. I'd argue this is the correct/better approach.